# ajax upload using iframe

Tags: html, ajax, forms, iframe

I need an information. If I have a form, used for uploading a file and having it target an Iframe.
I then use Ajax to get the Upload progress. Let say that a simple layout with 2
column only.

The Form being on column 1 and the Iframe on column 2. I want to still be 
able to use the column 1.

So while the the upload is still in process. Will I be able to use column 1 to show other page content?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, using a pre-built solution may solve your needs and provide greater functionality. I know that you can continue using the rest of the page when uploading via [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/). You may want to look into this.

Comment: Ohh thanks but i'm trying to use php uploadprogress extension with ajax. I can't use library

Answer (score 0):

Dont things to as everything upload process would have to finish first. You could display info in Collumn 1 prior to starting the Upload process. You wont be able to have any POST backs tho as that will cancel the upload process.

Flash/ASP could be your solution.

Comment: Sorry using ajax to change the content 1 i mean? Thus totally removing the form and replace it with new data. Still not?

Comment: No you could do that, simply change the output prior to starting the upload process.

Comment: Sorry kellax, haven't completely understand what you have said. You mean change the Column 1 content? And what do you mean by prior to starting the upload process? Is it before sending the form? How should i do that?